# How to integrate jitsi meet into aurelia

Tags: typescript, webpack, aurelia, script-tag

I am trying to integrate and use [Jitsi Meet](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/api.md) into my Aurelia application but without success so far..
As I see this library does not use modules and it does not have typescript declaration files.
On the library Github documentation page it says to just include script tag like this:

```
<script src='https://meet.jit.si/external_api.js'></script>
```

and then call the api like this:

```
const domain = 'meet.jit.si';
const options = {
    roomName: 'JitsiMeetAPIExample',
    width: 700,
    height: 700,
    parentNode: document.querySelector('#meet')
};
const api = new JitsiMeetExternalAPI(domain, options);
```

The problem is I can't find any article that tells me how can I use  tags in aurelia webpack also don't know where to put that  tag (intex, mycomponent.ts...) And at the end I get error saying that typescript cannot find module JitsiMeetExternalAPI.

I am using Aurelia with typescript and WebPack, but I can change to requirejs if it is easier to use it.

Please help

**Update:** 
I managed to get the tpescript part resolved by adding this to the viewModel:

```
declare var JitsiMeetExternalAPI: any;
```

With this my code compiles without errors.
I have added the cdn script tag at the end of the body in the index.ejs file.
So my index.ejs now looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><%- htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.title %></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <base href="<%- htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.baseUrl %>">
  </head>
  <body aurelia-app="main">
    <script src='https://meet.jit.si/external_api.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

my page looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="meet"></div>
</template>
```

When I start the application now, i see that the call was made to the cdnscript of jitsi but then I see an error of aurelia-router that says:

> [image: Blockquote]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Fund the problem,
The problem "appendChild" from aurelia was because it couldn't find the html element #meet because the view was not jet rendered. When I moved JitsiMeetExternalAPI initialization to a component, all works now.